# How to get event_id from this JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am working on API that retrieve the JSON data like below :

```
{"status":1,
"notification":
       [
        {
         "id":"175",
         "from_user":"3",
         "to_user":"7",
         "content":"Azri invited you to join the  Kaptr.",
         "is_read":"0",
         "type":"20",
         "created_date":"2014-04-17 04:11:02",
         "custom_prop":"{"status":1,
                         "api_name":"event_invite",
                         "event_id":155,
                         "event_name":false,
                         "invitee":"7"
                        }",
        "from_user_avatar_url":"http:\/\/app.kaptr.co\/vs\/kaptr_app\
        /images\/profile\/3\/1cAR7QSu.jpg"
         }
        ]
       }
```

I am trying to get the `event_id` under the `custom_prop` object. Is there any solution for me to solve this matter.

Comment: Check your response. its not valid json.

Comment: Hello Mr Chinttu, thanks for your response. What do you mean its not a valid json

Comment: you can get eventid after getting proper json response `[[[[Response objectForKey:@"notification"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"custom_prop" ] valueForKey:@"event_id"]`.

Comment: What is the code you are using now? @ChinttuRoxeNRamanian's answer should work.

Comment: its not valid JSON because here: `"custom_prop":"{ ... }"` it should be: `"custom_prop":{ ... }` (no quotes around curly braces)

Comment: Yup its correct, the json it self is not properly setup. Thanks guys for your help

Answer (score -1):

Try This :

```
   NSString *da = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"status\": \"1\",\"notification\": [{\"id\": \"175\",\"from_user\": \"3\",\"to_user\": \"7\",\"content\": \"Azri invited you to join the  Kaptr.\",\"is_read\": \"0\",\"type\": \"20\",\"created_date\": \"2014-04-17 04:11:02\",\"custom_prop\": [{\"status\": \"1\",\"api_name\": \"event_invite\",\"event_id\": \"155\",\"event_name\": \"false\",\"invitee\": \"7\"}],\"from_user_avatar_url\": \"string UTl\"}]}"];


    NSData* data1 = [da dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString * strdata =[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"responseone  %@", strdata);

    NSError *e = nil;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:kNilOptions error:&e];
    NSArray *myArray = [json objectForKey:@"notification"];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in myArray)
    {
        NSArray *myArray2 = [dict objectForKey:@"custom_prop"];

        for (NSDictionary *dict in myArray2)
        {
            NSString *eventId = [dict objectForKey:@"event_id"];
            NSLog(@"eventId = %@", eventId);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

so i don't come from the objective-c world i'm from .net, but i'm guessing solution will be the same, you have 2 approach to this problem:
 1. create an object that represent this JSON like:

```
      class SomeClass{
      public string Status {get;set;}
      public NotificationEnt[] {get;set;}
      }
      class NotificationEnt{
      public CustomProp {get;set;}
      }
      class CustomProp {
      public string event_Id {get;set;}
      }
```

and serialize it using your JSON serialize object ( I'm sure you got something )

or 
2. serialize it to a dynamic object ( i don't like this approach because it will leave you
with plenty room for exceptions and errors ).

hope this help putting you in the right direction.